# Printing Table Background Images with window.print()

Tags: css, image, printing, window

To the awesome folks of StackOverflow,

First off, I am no genius when it comes to coding. I am a basic HTML guy at best. I have created a certificate for users to print verifying the completion of a task and I cannot get the background image to print. I have gone through the site and can't wrap my head around all of the CSS-speak that people are tossing around. I need a simple solution that I can understand. Here's the table code:

```
<table id="certificate" border="0" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="2" background="images/certificate_border.png">
<tr>

    In recognition of successfully completing the course:<br>
    <strong>Quality Matters: Evolving Standards for Online Courses</strong>

    <h2>
        RMU Faculty<br> 
    </h2>

    <i>are hereby awarded this</i>

    <h3>Certificate of Completion</h3>

    </td>
</tr>
```

Thanks in advance for all of your help. It is greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Adam

Comment: Background images dont print. you need a proper image using <img>

Comment: Thanks Andrew. Can I use a proper <img> as a background for the table? I don't even know if that's possible.